# C++ Invalid conversion from char* to char (char* = *string.begin() )

Tags: c++, char, readfile

I've got the following code:

```
std::string extract() {

    fstream openfile("/home/name/Documents/testfile");
    std::string teststring;
    long location = 4;
    long length = 2;
    teststring.resize(length);
    char* begin = *teststring.begin();
    openfile.seekp(location);
    openfile.read(begin, length);

    return teststring;
}
```

This code is supposed to return a string of the characters found in a file. For example if the content of the file is

```
StackOverflow
```

this method should return

```
kO
```

This code was given to me by a friendly StackOverflow User. My problem is, that I get a Compile Error which says: "Invalid Conversion from char* to char". The problem is the

```
char* begin = *teststring.begin();
```

line. How can I fix this?

Comment: The LHS is a `char*`, while the RHS is a `char`. Simply remove the `*` from the RHS.

Comment: @Pavel Gatnar this gives the error code error: cannot convert 'std::basic_string<char>::iterator* {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >*}' to 'char*' in initialization

Comment: @bartgol a string iterator is not a char*

Comment: You're right. Silly me. Jose's reply is what I should have written: dereference and then take the address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

teststring.begin() returns an iterator, and if you dereference it with the `*` operator, you get a reference to a char (`char&`).

Therefore, you can  take it's address like:

```
char* begin = &*teststring.begin();
```

Or you can just do:

```
char* begin = &teststring[0];
```

Or

```
char* begin = &teststring.front() //(C++11) [@Jonathan Wakely]
```

The same thing goes for vectors. Altho in vector (C++11) a new function called `data()` was added which returns a pointer to T;

so with a vector you could just do

```
char * begin = myvector.data(); // (if T is char)
```

Comment: And another way: `&teststring.front()`

Comment: Updated, actually didn't know about that one (C+11 it seems). Was used to the other two.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I am using char* begin = &*teststring.begin(); and it works beautifully

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert the iterator value to the underlying data there is a trick to get the pointer to the first element.

```
auto iterator_testdata = testdata.begin();
char* first_element_in_testdata = &(*iterator_testdata);
```

Provided the iterator iterates char values.

This trick also works for vector::begin() and similar continuous containers. Use with care.